# Hard time understanding Taylor polynomials and MacLaurin?

Tags: calculus

I've gotten the definition that $$P_n$$ is a good approximation when :

$$ \lim_{x\to a} \frac{f(x)-P_n(x)}{{(x-a)}^n} = 0$$

But I am having a hard time understanding what that means.
Also:

We have a formula of something along the lines of

$$P_n(x) = c_0 + c_1(x) + c_2x^2 +...$$

But I don't understand what the meaning is and how it is different from the definition above.

If I were to asked to write the Taylor Polynomial for $$f(x) =x^3 $$ at a = 0. How would I find the values of $$P_2(x), P_3(x), P_4(x) $$and so on. Would it be 0 in every case. Because thats what I am getting.

Answer (score 1):

Notice that the constant function $0$ is a good first and second order approximation to $x^3$ because

$$\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{x^3 - 0}{x^n} = \lim_{x \to 0} x^{3 - n} = 0$$

provided that $n < 3$. If you consider any other approximation, such as $c_0  + c_1 x$, you would find that

$$\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{x^3 - c_0 - c_1 x}{x^n}$$

doesn't exist when $c_0$ and $c_1$ are both non-zero.

Of course this breaks down when $n = 3$, in which case $x^3$ is the best approximation (although a rather trivial one in this case... the Taylor series of a polynomial is just the polynomial itself). In that case, we have

$$\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{x^3 - x^3}{x^n} = 0$$

for all $n$.